# Array is undefined when there's actually a value AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Below is the code

```
UserRolesService.api.getUserRadaGroups({userLogin: $scope.selectedUserObj.login}, function(a) {
            _.each(a.radaGroups, function(c) {
                AuthorityRolesService.api.listForRadaGroup({radaGroup: c}, function(b) {
                    for(var i =0; i<b.length;i++){
                        console.log(b[i].roleName); //value will be like "Test","Advis..."
                        radaList.push(b[i].roleName);
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        console.log(radaList[0]);
```

When I console log radaList[0], the value is undefined.

However, when I console log radaList, the value will be as below

[image]

Appreciate any of your help on how  i can print the log of "Test"

I'm expecting, to get the print out "Test" which is value of 0 in radaList.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is `UserRolesService.api.getUserRadaGroups` an async task?

Answer (score 0):

As it seems in your response, you are getting an array of strings not objects, So it doesn't have roleName property.
try to modify your code as the following:

```
UserRolesService.api.getUserRadaGroups({userLogin: $scope.selectedUserObj.login}, function(a) {
            _.each(a.radaGroups, function(c) {
                AuthorityRolesService.api.listForRadaGroup({radaGroup: c}, function(b) {
                    for(var i =0; i<b.length;i++){
                        ***console.log(b[i]); //value will be like "Test","Advis..."
                        radaList.push(b[i]);***
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        console.log(radaList[0]);
```

Comment: I tried that earlier, still getting undefined.

Comment: can you print the json you get in b,use:  consol.log( JSON.stringify(b)) and post it please. also post the class/interface that you are expecting

Comment: The result for console.log that is {"roleId":21,"roleName":"TEST","deletable":false,"userInUse":0,"permissions":null,"radaGroups":["USERS"]}. I'm expecting, to get the print out "Test" which is value of 0 in radaList.

Comment: Ok, so you don't get an array, just use b.roleName

Comment: the reason i put it into an array because I will use the value of b[0] and b[1] in other place. any idea how i can do that?

Comment: Seems that listForRadaGroup is iterating over your array, In this case c is the array and b is each iteration

Comment: But when i console log radaList, i can see the value of 0 and 1. However when i console log radaList[0], the value is undefined

Comment: That's because you are doing that in the wrong place, Pay attention to the nested functions you have. The place you are printing radaList[0] is before you got the async results. I guess you need to understand a bit about async calls and how it works.  anyway, print the radaList[0] After exiting the for loop. this is the only place that the list is ready